# How to order posts on each different category?

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, right now only on my main blog page, I managed to sort all posts with:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'blog-category' ) ) : ?>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'blog-category' ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="blog_list_content">
<?php
           global $wp_query;
             $args =  array(
                'meta_key' => 'publish_date',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            );
            $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $args );
            query_posts( $args );
           if (have_posts()) :
               while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
               endwhile;
               theme_paging_nav();
           endif;
           ?>
```

What do I need to do in order to sort the posts on other categories in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct code. 
Copy and paste the same login in the single.php file of your theme and you'll get sorting for every category.